# Wildcard dns, non-existent subdomains point to main website

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard, subdomain

Before I start I'd like to say that I've already read relevant questions here on serverfault but I couldn't find a solution.

Here's my problem. I'm using a third party DNS and I've added a wildcard A record *.biglle.com which points to my server's ip address. The problem I'm having with that is that every non existent sub-domain points to biglle.com(those that do exist work fine). I'd like to note that the apache website configuration for biglle.com is not the default one (000-default.conf) but a separate one (biglle.com.conf). That's what I can't understand. The non-existent subdomains should point to the default configuration file, shouldn't they?

Here is part of biglle.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.54:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1004"
ServerName biglle.com
ServerAlias www.biglle.com
ServerAlias webmail.biglle.com
ServerAlias admin.biglle.com
DocumentRoot /home/biglle/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/biglle.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/biglle.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/biglle/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/biglle/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/biglle/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/biglle/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/biglle/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/biglle/cgi-bin>
allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.biglle.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://biglle.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.biglle.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://biglle.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "biglle.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/biglle/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
Alias /dav /home/biglle/public_html
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "biglle.com"
AuthUserFile /home/biglle/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://biglle.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://biglle.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
php_value memory_limit 32M
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently I'm using a php hack that checks if the domain name has a respective .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and if it doesn't it displays a 404 error but that's obviously not a permanent solution. Also this hack only works for the index page of each subdomain.

Due to me not having more than 10 rep I can't post examples here. You can see them on this paste here:
http://pastebin.com/cYY3ffYz

EDIT: apache2ctl -S output

```
root@biglle:/# apache2ctl -S
[Sun May 27 22:00:11 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 91.132.57.179:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.1.54:80        is a NameVirtualHost
         default server biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost fwnh.biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fwnh.biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost itemlist.biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itemlist.biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost lithisdoma.gr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lithisdoma.gr.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost think.biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/think.biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost topirouni.biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/topirouni.biglle.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost videos.biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/videos.biglle.com.conf:1)
192.168.1.54:443       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/biglle.com.conf:58)
         port 443 namevhost biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/biglle.com.conf:58)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: I'll edit it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache will look for VirtualHosts in the following order:

1. First defined VirtualHost with matching IP, port, and ServerName
2. First defined VirtualHost with matching IP and port
3. First defined VirtualHost with wildcard (or `_default_`) IP and matching port

I'm assuming that the server only has one IP address, namely 192.168.1.54.

```
192.168.1.54:80        is a NameVirtualHost
    default server biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/biglle.com.conf:1)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
    *:80                   biglle.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
```

Incoming requests on 192.168.1.54:80 which don't match a ServerName will therefore use the biglle.com VirtualHost defined in biglle.com.conf (because that is the first VirtualHost which matches the IP and port). The biglle.com VirtualHost in 000-default will only be used for requests received on an IP other than 192.168.1.54.

Unless you're actually doing IP based virtual hosting, I suggest that you change all your VirtualHosts to not specify an IP address (i.e. `<VirtualHost *:80>`), and make sure that the one you want to be the default is listed first in the configuration (which the 000-default file should do).

Comment: You can't imagine how long I've been looking for a fix to that problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Additional tips:

1. On some browsers (e.g. google chrome) you will only be able to browse and see the results of your apache config changes after restarting the browser.
2. Search for Redirect directives in the config files - they may also cause an issue.

Amnon